# Using radio buttons to tally a score in a quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, radio-button

I am trying to make a simple Javascript Quiz with radio buttons. Each question and options should be stored in an array, the questions being replaced dynamically with `getElementById()`. I am stuck trying to assign values for the radio buttons so that I can display the score at the end.

I am new to javascript and this is the first project I'm working on.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var questionsArray = new Array;
questionsArray[0] = ["1. Who is the president of the US?"];
questionsArray[1] = ["2. What is the capital city of France?"];
questionsArray[2] = ["3. What is your favorite food?"];
var choicesArray = new Array();
choicesArray[0] = ["Lebron James", "Barack Obama", "George Bush"];
choicesArray[1] = ["Nairobi", "London", "Paris"];
choicesArray[2] = ["Pizza", "Sushi", "Pasta"];
var i = 0;
var theScore = 0;

function btnOnclick() {
   var radElement = document.form1.options;
   var showDiv = document.getElementById("questionsDiv");
   showDiv.className = "showClass";
   document.getElementById("next").value = "Next";
   while(i < questionsArray.length && i < choicesArray.length) {
      var currQues = questionsArray[i];
      var option1 = choicesArray[i][0];
      var option2 = choicesArray[i][1];
      var option3 = choicesArray[i][2];
      i++;
      document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = currQues;
      document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = option1;
      document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = option2;
      document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = option3;
      return true
   }
   if(questionsArray[0] && radElement[1].checked == true) {
      theScore += 10
   } else {
      theScore += 0
   }
   if(questionsArray[1] && radElement[2].checked == true) {
      theScore += 10
   } else {
      theScore += 0
   }
   if(questionsArray[2] && radElement[1].checked == true) {
      theScore += 10
   } else {
      theScore += 0
   }
   alert(theScore)
}

function bodyOnload() {
   var hideDiv = document.getElementById("questionsDiv");
   hideDiv.className = "hideClass";
   document.getElementById("next").value = "Start Quiz"
}
```

```css
.hideClass{
  display: none;
}

.showClass{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body onload="bodyOnload()">
  <h1>QUIZ</h1>
  <div id="questionsDiv">
    <form name="form1">
      <p id="question" class="showQuestion"></p>
      <tr>
        <span id="choice1"></span>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" id="radio1" value="0" name="options" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="choice2"></span>
          <input type="radio" id="radio2" value="0" name="options" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="choice3"></span>
          <input type="radio" id="radio3" value="0" name="options" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="next" value="Next" name="nextButton"   onclick="btnOnclick()"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider structuring your answers as an array of objects, like this:

```
choicesArray[2] = [{
    text: "Pizza",
    correct: true
}, {
    text: "Pasta",
    correct: false
}, {
    text: "Sushi",
    correct: false
}];
```

Then, if `radio2` is selected, you check the second item in the answers array to see if it is correct, like this:

```
// use index 1 for the second choice in the list.
if(choicesArray[2][1].correct === true) {
    //it's right!
} else {
    //it's wrong...
}
```

You obviously have a ways to go before you get this functional , but that's my first suggestion.

You could take it a step further (I would!) and put the questions and answers together for easy reference:

```
var question = {
    questionText: 'What is your favorite food?',
    answers: [{
        answerText: "Pizza",
        correct: true
    }, {
        answerText: "Pasta",
        correct: false
    }, {
        answerText: "Sushi",
        correct: false
    }]
};
```

Then you can access things like this:

```
var currentQuestionIndex = 1; //or whatever it is

var questionText = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].questionText;

var answer1 = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].answers[0].answerText;
var answer1isCorrect = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].answers[0].correct;

var answer2 = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].answers[1].answerText;
var answer2isCorrect = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].answers[1].correct;

var answer3 = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].answers[2].answerText;
var answer3isCorrect = questionsArray[currentQuestionIndex].answers[2].correct;
```

Also, you don't need to be so explicit when adding items to your array. It makes your code brittle. Consider using `push()`:

```
var questionsArray = [];

questionsArray.push({
    questionText: 'What is your favorite food?',
    answers: [{
        answerText: "Pizza",
        correct: true
    }, {
        answerText: "Pasta",
        correct: false
    }, {
        answerText: "Sushi",
        correct: false
    }]
});
```